# Is there a long form of #I?

Tags: f#

For consistency reasons I prefer to write `#reference` instead of `#r` in my script files:

```ml
#reference "System.Xaml"
#reference "PresentationCore"
#reference "PresentationFramework"
#reference "WindowsBase"

// instead of

#r "System.Xaml"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "WindowsBase"
```

But if I want to reference a DLL not in the GAC or the script directory, I have to add the directory to the search path with `#I`, like so:

```ml
#I @"C:\libs\whatever\"
```

I was wondering if there is also a long version of `#I`. The [F# Interactive Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx) does not even mention that `#reference` is a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not even sure a long form does exist.

Looking at [interactive options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx) we can see that `-r` option is a shortcut for `--reference` and in the same way `-I` is a shortcut for `--lib`.

Unfortunately trying `#lib` or `#library` doesn't work.
Similarily trying `#Include` (which could be a good assumption of what `I` could stand for) just tell us that include is a reserved keyword for future use.

Comment: Yeah I tried `#Include` too... I'm looking through the interpreter source code, maybe it's just really unintuitive.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't exist... [Here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/17b7f2060894d90481aef7c9625b78faa50eddd2/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L1639) is the line matching `#I`, and [right above it](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/17b7f2060894d90481aef7c9625b78faa50eddd2/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L1619) is the line matching both `#r` and `#reference`. Shame. But it turns out there are some directives I've never even heard of... `#cd` and `#silentCd` for example.

Comment: @NikontheThird the cd directive is there to mimic the existing one available in "classic windows command line" to allow changing the working directory without having to quit fsi first

Comment: Interesting, that might actually come in handy.